# how to wpautop keep <br> in wordpress comment?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the auto `<p> and </p>` inside my comment in wordpress.

I can use

```
remove_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop', 30 );
```

But it also remove the `<br>` :(

What is the correct way to keep the `<br>` to not being removed?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use PHP's [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in place of WordPress' `wpautop`.

```
remove_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop', 30 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'nl2br', 30 );
```